# Can git SHA be displayed as part of a software version for an electronic device

Tags: git, version, sha

I would like to use and display a fairly standard semantic versioning MM.mm.bb  = (M)ajor.(m)inor.(b)uild, but ideally I would like something computer generated, because I don't want to auto-increment the build number due to a peculiarity with this device.

I was thinking of trying to include the git SHA, but of course the SHA is not output until you form a commit.

Is it possible/reasonable to include the SHA in a software build version (for example: MM.mm.bb-f9a8e8)?

Given that I don't want to auto-increment build number and don't particularly want to add an additional SHA calculation other than the git one, Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Linux kernel does this. Look into its source to get how it does a trick (hint: it recompiles a version file in case versio has been changed).

Comment: So when I say "use" I mean "display" -- not only do I want to have the SHA as part of the version but I also want to have it is a string somewhere in the code so that I can "use" (diplay) it.  Do you think your parallel still applies @0andriy?

Comment: That's exactly what Linux kernel does. Simple read its sources.

Comment: The script which extracts the local version https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/setlocalversion

Comment: There are a number of things I don't understand about what's going on in these makefiles and c code.  I guess it's theoretically possible, but I still don't understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I pointed out in the comments, Linux kernel does the trick. The main part there is the [setlocalversion](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/scripts/setlocalversion) script, the core part of which is (detailed explanations are given inside the original script, below are only crucial parts)

```sh
    if test -z "$(git rev-parse --show-cdup 2>/dev/null)" &&
       head=$(git rev-parse --verify --short HEAD 2>/dev/null); then
            if [ -z "$(git describe --exact-match 2>/dev/null)" ]; then
                    printf '%s%s' -g $head
            fi

            if {
                    git --no-optional-locks status -uno --porcelain 2>/dev/null ||
                    git diff-index --name-only HEAD
            } | grep -qvE '^(.. )?scripts/package'; then
                    printf '%s' -dirty
            fi
    fi
```

Now our C file *module.c*:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "version.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Our version is: %s\n", VERSION);
    return 0;
}
```

and *Makefile*

```make
VERSION = 0.1

version.h: FORCE
    @echo "$(VERSION)$(shell $(PWD)/setlocalversion $(PWD))"
    @echo "#define VERSION \"$(VERSION)$(shell $(PWD)/setlocalversion $(PWD))\"" > version.h


module.o: version.h

all: module
    @$(PWD)/module

clean:
    @rm module module.o version.h

FORCE:

.PHONY: FORCE
```

Show time:

```sh
$ make all
0.1-gb6d5c80
cc    -c -o module.o module.c
cc   module.o   -o module
Our version is: 0.1-gb6d5c80
```

Comment: so version.h would need to be an unversioned file correct? (otherwise it will necessarily change the git SHA).  Also it seems like you would want to make sure that other files are unchanged otherwise you might not build the files from this SHA ... other than version.h.

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. I didn't get what you mean. The _dirty_ suffix in version string is a marker that something based on given commit, but not commited has been built. Just try above.